# not able to show marathi text in pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 88f, 88f, 10f, 10f);
    Font NormalFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        Phrase phrase = null;
        PdfPCell cell = null;
        PdfPTable table = null;
        Color color = null;

        document.Open();

        //Header Table
        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.TotalWidth = 500f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 0.7f });


        //Company Name and Address
        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk(" pdf demo  \n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16, Font.BOLD, Color.RED)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("Aurangabad, Maharashtra 431116,\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("India\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        // phrase.Add(new Chunk("Seattle, USA", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Separater Line
        color = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A9A9A9"));
        DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 79f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 79f, color);
        DrawLine(writer, 25f, document.Top - 80f, document.PageSize.Width - 25f, document.Top - 80f, color);
        document.Add(table);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.3f, 1f });
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;

        //Employee Details
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase("Certificate Record", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingTop = 30f;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 30f;

        table.AddCell(cell);

        ////Photo
        //cell = ImageCell(string.Format("~/photos/{0}.jpg", dr["id"]), 25f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //table.AddCell(cell);


        //String tgender = dr["gender"].ToString();
        //String tchild_no = dr["child_no"].ToString();


        phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("प्रिया", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("name", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
        cell = PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        document.Add(table);

        //DrawLine(writer, 160f, 80f, 160f, 690f, Color.WHITE);
        //DrawLine(writer, 115f, document.Top - 200f, document.PageSize.Width - 100f, document.Top - 200f, Color.WHITE);

        table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 0.5f, 2f });
        table.TotalWidth = 340f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;



           //name
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Name:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("" + "प्रिया", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
        table.AddCell(cell);


        document.Add(table);
        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Certificate.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        Response.Close();
    }
}

private static void DrawLine(PdfWriter writer, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, Color color)
{

    PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
    contentByte.SetColorStroke(color);
    contentByte.MoveTo(x1, y1);
    contentByte.LineTo(x2, y2);
    contentByte.Stroke();
}
private static PdfPCell PhraseCell(Phrase phrase, int align)
{
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
    cell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = align;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 2f;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0f;
    return cell;
}

private static PdfPCell ImageCell(string path, float scale, int align)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
    image.ScalePercent(scale);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image);
    cell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_TOP;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = align;
    cell.PaddingBottom = 0f;
    cell.PaddingTop = 0f;
    return cell;
}
```

not able to show marathi text in pdf, I tried many online solutions but still not get success. Please check my code and give solution.

Comment: What happens with your code compared to what you are expecting? Can you add any other text?

Comment: pdf show english text properly, but it not showing marathi text i.e. priya which I write in marathi language,

Comment: Does it show any other text in place of the marathi text you're expecting?

Comment: no, it not showing anything

Comment: @PriyaPatil - Try to give mangal font in FontFactory.GetFont() method instead of Arial. This font support Unicode so it may work.

Comment: I was going to similarly suggest another font, Google Noto Fonts say they aim "to support all languages with a harmonious look and feel" https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Comment: @Mayur Lohite- mangal font is not working, giving same problem

Comment: Noto font is also not working